# how do I import java class in build.gradle file

Tags: java, gradle, import, build.gradle

I want to import static data in build.gradle file from below class:

```
 public class MyClass{
     public static final String PROPERTY_A = "myStringA";
     public static final String PROPERTY_B = "myStringB";
  }
```

I saw a project where they used, something like:

```
import com.example.MyClass
```

but I couldn't figure out what configurations are to be provided in order to have the visibility of java class from build.gradle.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `buildSrc`: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources

So for your example, your directory structured would look something like:

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── buildSrc
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── com
│       │           └── example
│       │               └── MyClass.java
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── example
│                       └── MyClassTest.java
└── settings.gradle
```

Then you would just import as you have above.

Comment: Thank you for responding! This was really helpful.